# C5.0 decision tree - input string 1 is invalid in this locale

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have read the questions related before, but still can not solve my problem, my training data does not have missing values, so I don't know where it was wrong.

Another problem is the tree size is 1, all predicted results are 0 (label is 0 or 1 ). I know this is  an extremely unbalanced case (the 0 label take up  98%), how do I solve the problem?

```
model_boost<-C5.0(train,train_label)
```

Error:

> c50 code called exit with value 1

Warning message:

> In `strsplit(Z$output, "\n")`: input string 1 is invalid in this locale

training data:

> str(train)
>   'data.frame':   7500 obs. of  148 variables:
>    $ CI_CUSTYPE                  : Factor w/ 4 levels "个人","家庭",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
>    $ CI_COUNTRY_FLAG             : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
>    $ CI_AGE                      : int  -1 44 31 53 58 -1 -1 46 43 61 ...
>    $ CI_GENDER                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "男","女","未知": 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 1 ...
>    $ CI_CITY                     : Factor w/ 21 levels "阿坝","巴中",..: 16 18 9 3 3 4 5 1 3 19 ...
>    $ CI_TENURE                   : int  4 44 205 92 92 26 9 110 24 48 ...
>    $ IS_DUAL_MODE                : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","1","2","3": 2 2 2 1 2 1 4 4 4 2 ...
>    $ PD_CDMA_PAYMODE             : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 ...
>    $ PD_CDMA_TENURE              : int  49 43 64 39 19 36 8 52 15 47 ...
>    $ VO_MOU_TOTAL_AVG            : int  9520 344 2287 253 460 249 3 885 623 457 ...

train_label

> str(train_label)
>    Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 .
>   print(head(train_label))
>   [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   Levels: 0 1

Comment: Is this all your code? You should provide enough to solve the problem.

Comment: It seems that your response variable (or maybe one of the partitioning variables) is a factor or character with some special non-ASCII symbols in it. You can start by simply looking at it (i.e. `print()` it) but the special characters could also be non-standard spces. Or check the `Encoding()`...

Comment: thanks for  your answering my questions,but my encoding seems right.In R,they all looked  encode right;  I have added my data on it ,I have planned to pose the images of the output,but I failed. I am sorry for it looks teriible.

Comment: You could try to replace `levels(CI_CUSTYPE)` and `levels(CI_GENDER)` and `levels(CI_CITY)` with ASCII transliterations of the original names. My guess is that this solves the error message. And if it does you need to investigate wether the `Encoding(CI_CUSTYPE)` etc. was correctly declared and is compatible with your `Sys.getlocale()`.